# Fail build if dependency fails

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

Is there any way to have a build wait until its dependency builds run and fail if they fail?  I cant find one outside of this 700 dollar plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1210988/run-cli-actions-in-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview

Answer (score 0):

You will want to break the build up into multiple plans. You can set one of the builds to be dependent on the other plan under the "Dependencies" tab in Plan Configuration.  There are different strategies for controlling how these dependencies trigger and block under the "Advanced options" dropdown.

Atlassian has a guide on this here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/setting-up-plan-build-dependencies-289276887.html